# css3 flex: why img take more width than contains?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

1. Why `.itm` in this case take width `400px` instead of `160px`? In other cases div take same width like child, but when img is bigger and browser scale it - I got empty space
2. How to fix it? I fount only one way: set `<img height="..." width="..." />`, but I want more more suitable way because I don't know real image size.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}
.box .itm {
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.box .itm img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.box .itm .tst {
  width: 160px;
  height: 400px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="itm">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/750"/>
  </div>
  <div class="itm">
    <div class="tst">same block with 160x400 sime like img</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have just provided `max-width` which would adjust the elements according to the maximum it can stretch to. Try replacing it with `width` and check.

Comment: @m4n0
hm, I did it because I need dynamic sizing. Pictures can be with different size and ratio and I want to fit it.

Comment: if your image height is bigger that its width then you will always get this output. Remove max-height:100% to understand why you get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I didn't understand why this is happening
2. I fixed this by moving the max-width directly to each image. In my case, this solves the problem, but it would not help if there was not only a picture but also other content in the container.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
}
.box .itm {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.box .itm img {
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.box .itm .tst {
  width: 160px;
  height: 400px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="itm">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/750"/>
  </div>
  <div class="itm">
    <div class="tst">same block with 160x400 sime like img</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

As the flex items do not have `width` or `flex-basis` properties defined, `flex` container space distributed as first element will take the `max-width` size, and the second item will take the remaining space.

**Solution**

Add `width` and `flex-basis` properties to flex items

Comment: images can be with any different sizes, flex items have to be with dynamic width (depended on image size), I cant set one static width for all `itm`.